# .id_rsa.swp file found in user ssh directory, is that normal?

Tags: linux, ssh

Im a bit of a noob when it comes to using linux OS.  On my local machine I have noticed a new file within the user .ssh directory as the following:-

.id_rsa.swp

is that normal ?

I definitely didn't make myself im sure of that.

Thanks
J

Comment: What have you researched so far? This seems like it could be a common question.  Doing research before asking here is expected. Even though I'm not a Linux guy, having an extension of swp seems like it would be a "swap file", or virtual memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not normal but its probably benign. You should check the contents of that file and then delete it if its older or the same as your id_rsa file.

.filename.swp is a standard way that VI (and possibly other editors) modify and lock a file -  if you were looking at the id_rsa file in vi and did not properly exit this file would remain, and when you next tried to edit vi it would know/complain about someone else editing it. If the id_rsa file contains what you need it us safe to delete this file.

Comment: Ok yeah I think you are correct.  I have deleted now :-)